# Why does my property Client refresh everytime? and how can I refresh my inputs when client is changed? livewire

Tags: javascript, laravel, web, crud, laravel-livewire

I'm doing test and I realize that the atributte called client, refresh everytime the component renders, for example

I'm gonna update this record.
[image]

but if someones update it before me the model get updated but the inputs not
[image]

this is my code and I don't know where the client refresh every render

```
class ClientForm extends Component
{
use WithFileUploads;
public $nombre, $razonsocial, $logo, $logoFile, $idUsuario, $userOptions, $client_id, $client;

protected $validationAttributes = [
    'nombre' => 'nombre',
    'razonsocial' => 'razon Social',
    'logo' => 'logo',
    'logoFile' => 'logo',
    'idUsuario' => 'usuario',
    'clientOptionSelected' => 'cliente'
];

public function __construct()
{
    $this->userOptions = User::doesntHave('cliente')->get();
}

public function mount()
{
    if ($this->client_id) {
        $this->client = Cat_Cliente::findorFail($this->client_id);
        $this->fillInputs();
    }
}

private function fillInputs()
{
    if ($this->client->usuario) {
        $this->idUsuario = $this->client->idUsuario;
        $this->userOptions = $this->userOptions->merge([User::find($this->idUsuario)]);
    }
    $this->client_id = $this->client->idCliente;
    $this->nombre = $this->client->nombre;
    $this->logo = $this->client->logo;
    $this->razonsocial =  $this->client->razonsocial;
}

protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'nombre' => 'required|max:50|min:1',
        'razonsocial' => 'required|max:50|min:1',
        'logoFile' => 'nullable|image',
        'idUsuario' => ['required', 'numeric', 'exists:TB_Usuario,idUsuario', 'unique:Cat_Cliente,idUsuario']
    ];
}

private function updateRules()
{
    $rules = $this->rules();
    $rules['idUsuario'] = ['required', 'numeric', 'exists:TB_Usuario,idUsuario', Rule::unique('Cat_Cliente', 'idUsuario')->ignore($this->client_id, 'idCliente')];
    return $rules;
}

public function updatedLogoFile($value)
{
    $this->logo = $value;
}

public function store()
{
    $validData = $this->validate();
    $validData['logo'] = ImageBlobHelper::getImageBlob($validData['logoFile']);
    if (!Cat_Cliente::create($validData)) {
        session()->flash('error', "Ha ocurrido un error");
    }
    $this->emit('ClientCreated');
    $this->reset();
    session()->flash('success', "Se ha creado el cliente");
}

public function update()
{
    $valid = $this->validate($this->updateRules());
    $valid['logo'] = ImageBlobHelper::getImageBlob($valid['logoFile']);
    $this->client->update($valid);
    session()->flash('success', "Se ha modificado el cliente");
    $this->emit('ClientUpdated');
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.admin.client.client-form');
}
}
```

Can u guys tell me why the client get updated every render? and how can I tell the user that the record has changed by another person and refresh the inputs?